# Make a Button Responsive and Centered Horizontally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a website and I'm trying to make a button that is centered and responsive but it is just not working!

HTML:

```
<div id="button-container">
  <button id="who-are-we" class="font-spec">quem somos</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button-container {
    width: 120px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
  }

#who-are-we {
    font-family: Volkorn;
    background: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 180%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width:220px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

I tried messing with the margins but there must be a simpler way of doing this, I am also trying to make the button smaller when the window gets smaller.

Comment: You need button vertical or horizontal center?

Comment: edited that part, totally forgot to mention it hahah sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear if you want vertical or horizontal centering, but here is an example of horizontal centering, and the button is `width:30%;` of the page. The button is centered because its parent is 100% width (by default because it is a `div`) and has `text-align: center;` which centers all the child elements.

```css
#button-container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }

#who-are-we {
    font-family: Volkorn;
    background: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:30%;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
  <button id="who-are-we" class="font-spec">quem somos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked thanks i just had to add margin-left and right: auto and it works like a charm when trying to align horizonatlly

Answer (score 2):

Use percentages (%) when assigning widths and heights.

Also, I don't get why the #who-are-we width (220px) is greater than the #button-container width (120px)

Here's an example:

```css
#button-container {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

#who-are-we {
    font-family: Volkorn;
    background: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 180%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width:220px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
  <button id="who-are-we" class="font-spec">quem somos</button>
</div>
```